# Immediately spin down a HDD on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, storage, hard-drive

I have 2 non-system SATA HDDs which are not mapped to a dir and normally kept 'offline' on my Windows 7 OS. Even this way they spin up from time to time, including but not limited to windows update times.

It's easy on Linux but, what is the best way to spin down a HDD on demand using as small 3rd party software as possible on Windows? Or even, is there a 3rd party software allowing this?

Comment: I've voted up the question because I'd love to know the answer too. Since you have a (good) tendency to answer your own questions, I'll keep this one favourited.

Comment: Have you tried going into Device Manager, Disk Drives, right clicking and disabling the individual drives?

Comment: Strange, I barely leave any comment with no replies, and I'm nearly sure I did reply to all comments in this question. Are my comments lost or what?

Answer (score 20):

Since you are familiar with Linux, stick to the `smartctl` command-line utility of [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download#InstalltheWindowspackage). You can spin down disks with the `-s` switch.
From the [man page](https://www.smartmontools.org/browser/trunk/smartmontools/smartctl.8.in):

> **-s NAME[,VALUE], --set=NAME[,VALUE]**
>   *standby,now* - [ATA only] Places the drive in the STANDBY mode. This usually spins down the drive. The setting of the standby timer is not affected.

It requires an elevated prompt and the Linux /dev/sdX-style of referring to disks when they are unmapped, otherwise:

```
> smartctl.exe -s standby,now d:
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-w64-mingw32-win10] (sf-6.5-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Device placed in STANDBY mode
```

Unfortunately, there is not much to prevent Windows from spinning the disks back up again whenever it so pleases.

Comment: Regarding preventing Windows from spinning disks up again - could a driver be implemented to guard against such events, by requiring user intervention to enable a disk to be spun up and otherwise replying that the drive is not available to spurious Windows service touch requests or whatever else it feels like doing when it necessitates a spin up?

Comment: PROBLEM with smartctl... when i spin down one external drive, it will spin up the others! :\ Why does it access other drives?

Comment: Opened a ticket: https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/1496#ticket

Answer (score 4):

For many years I've been using utility **[RevoSleep](https://www.meinfach.net/revosleep/)** for exactly that purpose - it has simple taskbar popup menu that allows to manually spin-down (sleep) or spin-up (wake) any hard drive of your computer.

While this tool is made almost 8 years ago (for Windows XP originally), it still works even these days in Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

Its not immediate, but you approximate what you're after by using `Control Panels > Power Options` to power down your harddrive after a set amount of idleness e.g. 1 min.

Comment: Yes, however that setting applies to all drives including the system drive; which would result in a start-stop loop with an extremely high frequency, shortening the life of your HDD and degrade performance and more noise.

Comment: @SuperDuck - Noted. Please note this was a genuine error and not part of a cunning plan to get people to move onto OS X/ Linux ;)

Comment: lol - ok, noted =)

Comment: Nearly 13 years later, this answer is now much more applicable with most OS drives being SSDs. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 7, "HDDScan" version v3.3 worked for me.  Startup HDDScan, select your disk from the drop-down box, click the icon of the magnifying glass overtop the hard disk, click Features -> IDE Features, click Spindown.

Looks like there is also an option to set an inactivity timer.

I downloaded the program from here: http://majorgeeks.com/HDDScan_for_Windows_d6321.html

I was originally going to download Devcon but this was much quicker and I'm on a limited data plan.

Comment: Worked well for me.

Comment: it works! but... is there another way to spin down without going into a user interface of a program?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft provides a command line tool called [Devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272).
You can write down batch processes to disable/enable your hardware devices using it.

Comment: Is enabling/disabling synonymous with spinning down a hard disk though? I have just disabled two HDD but I believe they are still spinning

Comment: @deed02392 It does disable (and spin down) disks completely. It is equal to disabling devices with the Device Manager.

Comment: I tried disabling it, but it said that computer reboot is needed. So it's useless.

Comment: @Nickolodeon it might be because there was some application that was running on the h/w you were trying to spin down.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to set the drive spin down time in the drive firmware to immediately spin down. I've done this in FreeBSD using ataidle.

There seems to be a windows tool to do this, but I've never used it. Use at your own risk
http://linux.wareseeker.com/System/ataidle-2.5.zip/291be59b53

The benefit here is that the *drive* is controlling its spin-down time, so it'll work the same way anywhere without a program watching it.

Comment: Hmm... My solution isn't on-demand in fact. It might become troublesome when trying to use the drives normally.

Why don't you mark them disabled in Windows 7 hardware manager? That might make sure they won't spin-up in the first place. And... this suggestion was already mentioned. Go me.

Answer (score 0):

It's the applications which try to access these drives if you havent told windows indexer to index those drives. you can use resource monitor to see which applications are accessing or have recently accessed to which hard drives. you can configure applications using their own settings pages,forms etc.

Comment: Thanks. As this question is from 6 years back, I don't currently have the environment to test it. However, when you switch a disk to offline, Windows and you won't see files'n folders, not even volumes and drive letters. As there are no files or volumes, normal applications won't see the drive, and the resource monitor won't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

There are `hdparam` executable runable on windows that function similar to `hdparam` on linux.

Just search for `hdparam.exe`