# How to power off a secondary internal hard drive using software?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive

Sometimes, there is a need to shut down a secondary internal hard drive (for example, due to the noise it produces while it's running). I would like to do this without physically disconnecting the drive in question. I didn't find any relevant piece of information on how to do this.

Comment: Related (and almost a duplicate, considering the options are also available on XP): [How can I force an internal hard drive to power on or off when I want?](http://superuser.com/q/365286/228536)

Answer (score 0):

Is the secondary drive an internal drive or is it an external drive?

If it's an internal drive you should be able to disable the drive via Computer Management. START > Right click "My Computer" > Properties > Device Manager > Find HDD in question and right click, go to properties, in properties you should see a drop down with an option to disable the device.

If it's an external drive, the drive should be able to be turned off manually - via a switch or unplug the external HDD.

Comment: But that won't power off the drive.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the OP. @ChrisInEdmonton So do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try [hdparm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdparm) ([for Windows](https://sites.google.com/site/disablehddapm/home)).

The Wikipedia article mentions acoustic management as well as spindown settings. I'm not sure if powering off entirely is an option or not.